# how can I make the webdriver click on element as soon as it is clickable , instead of loading of entire page?

Tags: java, webdriver

"Register as new user" link text appears on home page , as soon as webdriver get it (driver.get) . But still it waits for entire page to load up to execute below line.

```
driver.findelement(By.linkText("Register as new user")).click();
```

how can it be possible that webdriver click on the element as soon as it appears on the page, no matter other elements appeared or not.
I am using: JAVA, Ubuntu.

Comment: I think WebDriver needs the page to be fully loaded so it can read the DOM properly. I might be mistaken too, often times i am.

Comment: Implicit wait, if set, waits for every findElement call. Use explicit wait as given in one of the answers here, but make sure that Implicit wait is removed.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether the implicit wait makes the *driver* wait till the page is fully loaded especially after opening an URL. But it is worth trying explicit wait. The below code makes the driver wait till the element becomes clickable then clicks on it. Should the element doesn't become clickable in the specified time(in the below example it is set to 30 seconds) then driver throws *TimeoutException*.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30//unit time in seconds);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Register as new user"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the FireFoxDriver profile setting to make Firefox not wait for the full page to load after calling **.click**

```
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.SetPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
```

Answer (score 0):

Bracket the wait.until ... statement like so:

turnOffImplicitWaits();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Register as new user"))).click();
turnOnImplicitWaits();

Comment: Tried to add this as a comment to Code Enthusiastic's reply but couldn't format the comment text.